# Ionic 2 Modal not showing

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I've followed the example given on [Ionic2 modals](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/Modal/) and am not getting any errors but when I click the card that should initiate the modal nothing happens.

Here is the code for the modal itself:

```
@Component ({
    template: `
        <ion-card class='popover'>
            <ion-card-content>
                Hello
            </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
    `
})

export class AccModal {

    dumbData: number;
    constructor() {
         console.log("constructor");
         this.dumbData= 22;
    }
}
```

The page where my modal will be presented looks like this:

```
<ion-card (click)='presentModal()' class='custom-card'>
    <ion-card-header>
        Sched. Accuracy
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
        71%
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

With the typescript like this:

```
presentModal() {
    let myModal = Modal.create(AccModal, {param: "something"});
    console.log('myModal is ', myModal);
    this.nav.present(myModal);
    console.log("function being called");
}
```

The `console.log` in the `presentModal` is being registered but the one in the constructor of the modal is NOT. I'm at a loss on what to do because I'm not 100% sure whats going on?

**UPDATE**

When I debug into the nav.present (Nav Controller function) here is what I see:

```
if (rootNav['_tabs']) {
    // TODO: must have until this goes in
    // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5481
    void 0;
    return;
}
```

My project does have tabs in it so that statement evaluates to true and the present function effectively returns me a 0 and calls it good. In my package.json my ionic versions are: `"ionic-angular": "^2.0.0-beta.8", 
"ionic-native": "^1.1.0"`

Hopefully this added information helps diagnose for someone smarter than myself.

**UPDATE 2**:

I've updated to the latest ionic 2 release in 2.0.0-beta.9. However, when I debug in the chrome console I still see the code above in my nav.present function in the ionic-angular code, EVEN THOUGH when I look at it in my own code I see this:

```
if (rootNav['_tabs']) {
  // TODO: must have until this goes in
  // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5481
  console.error('A parent <ion-nav> is required for ActionSheet/Alert/Modal/Loading');
  return;
}
```

I've cleared my cache and hard reloaded the page and still the old code shows up. I must be losing my mind. Any insight on this would be amazing.

**Update 3**

Here is the code for my tabs. The live in the app.html and the index variable is just a way to start the app on the right tab. It starts as 1(or the second tab):

```
<ion-tabs greenTheme [selectedIndex]="index">
    <ion-tab tabIcon="people" #content tabTitle="My Roster" [root]="tab2"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="stats" #content tabTitle="Wage Overview" [root]="tab1"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Is your this.nav your nav controller?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I left out the constructor

Comment: `.present(myModal)` returns a promise. Try doing `.present(myModal).then((res) => { debugger; }).catch((err) => { debugger;})` to see if any useful information is returned here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ionic 2 beta 11, the update fixed the issue. The only difference in my code from the example [here on ionic's site](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/ModalController/) is the template for my modal. Super simple, and straightforward on how it's done.

Answer (score 5):

I know nothing about the code that handles the tabs, but I created a Plunker with the code in this post (and a pretty small change), and the modal shows up properly.

The change I made, is in the modal code:

```
// Add NavParams to use it later in the modal's constructor
import { ..., NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component ({
    template: `
        <ion-card class='popover'>
            <ion-card-content>
                Hello
            </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
    `
})
export class AccModal {

  private dumbData: number;

  // I've added the params variable, because you're calling this constructor
  // with a parameter (called 'param' and with the 'something' value)
  constructor(private params: NavParams) {

   console.log("constructor");
   this.dumbData= 22;

   // You can see in the console the parameter being printed properly
   console.log('Param:', params.get('param'));
 }

}
```

You can play around with [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/klYKiMdv1tsXtIn2FlGK?p=preview) (Ionic2 beta.9).

====================================

**UPDATE:**

I've updated the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/klYKiMdv1tsXtIn2FlGK?p=preview) to include a `tab` layout, and it works as expected.

> The live in the app.html...

I tried to make it work including the tabs in the `app.html` but couldn't do it. So, I've added the tabs in a `home page` which only contains both tabs, and in the `app.ts` I just set `this.rootPage = HomePage;` so that is the first page of the application. Could you try doing this in your app, to see if including the tabs in the `app` page could be realted to the issue?

Comment: I think the tabs issue is the crux of the issue because, as shown in the code above, the present function first checks if the nav has tabs and if it does, returns 0, effectively not rendering my modal.

Comment: Is there a simple way to replicate the code related with your tabs in that plunker? That way I would be able to debug it and take a closer look at what's going on internally.

Comment: I added my tab html. In the app.js I assigned tab1 and tab2 variables to actual components that serve as their own page.

Comment: I've updated the plunker. Please tell me if that fix the issue or helps anyway.

Comment: Sorry its been so long since replying. What you can do to change your plunker so that it more represents my code is in your app.ts file, change the template from `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>` to `<ion-tabs [selectedIndex]="0">
    <ion-tab tabIcon="people" #content tabTitle="My Roster" [root]="rootPage"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="stats" #content tabTitle="Wage Overview" [root]="tab1"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>`

Answer (score -1):

Import the NavController in your constructor like so:

```
constructor(private navController: NavController) {
  // Whatever goes here
}
```

And your method call `this.navController.present(myModal);`

Comment: Sorry. What I meant to say in my comment was that I AM importing the nav controller just like you are here(except mine is just called nav) I just don't think it's necessary to add to the code in my question.